# Jquery 4nth child selecting 2nd child

Tags: jquery, html

I have four divs in my page

```
 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="blue"></div>
```

and trying to highlight 4th item to add a class and become yellow. Issue I'm facing is it keep selecting 2nd div and not fourth

and here is my jquery

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".blue:nth-child(4n+4)").addClass('yellow');;
    });
    </script>
```

I'm not an expert in JQuery however im sure selecting 4n should do the job and having 4n+4 should make 4th div yellow and then 8th and then 12th

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Seems to work  just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/myd7y/1/

Comment: working here http://jsfiddle.net/e332W/ show us a fiddle which is not working!

Comment: I'm guessing there are more elements, as in two children in the same parent before the first .blue element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  $(".blue:eq(3)").addClass('yellow');
```

**[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jmmLF/)**

or

```
  $(".blue:nth-child(4)").addClass('yellow');
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jmmLF/1/)**

Comment: I tried this and im sure what you are saying is correct but still selecting 2nd one, could it be something causing this? my jquery version is 1.11.0

Comment: @user3482036:would be great if you can share the fiddle. both the demos i gave,works fine in fiddle.

Comment: Sure, one thing i realised is that it doesnt matter what nth child i use, it always select the second one

Comment: @user3482036: ohh that is very weird. would be great to see the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".blue:nth-child(4n+4)").addClass('yellow'); is incorrect !
```

If you want to select 4th child, you should use nth-child(4)

So use,

```
 $(".blue:nth-child(4)").addClass('yellow');
```

And this should do !

Comment: That does something completely different, it selects **only** the fourth child, not the eight etc ...

Comment: You had to select the fourth child right ?
that is what you have posted in the question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve then ?

Comment: He's  trying to achive 4n+4, which would select 4,8,12 etc, not just the fourth, read the question, but for some reason it selects the second child instead, which this answer in no way solves, if I'm undertanding this correctly ?